Nextjs 14 - Add Header to *EVERY* http Requests without using Service Worker
I would like to add a header to EVERY outgoing http request (for both pages and api).
Is there build in way to do so globally in nextjs?
Context:
I use Firebase's App Hosing to host nextjs 14 app.
Due to technical issue, it does not support Set-Cookie at this point, hence no cookies,  hence I cannot follow the best prcatices for authentication/authorization documented in nextjs site (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/authentication).
I'd like to add Bearer token to every http requests the browser makes to the server without using service worker
